# os_log_debug unresolved identifier while importing os or os.log

Tags: swift

Xcode prompt an error while using os_log_debug, os_log_info, ... "use unresolved identifier 'os_log_debug'"

I use "import os.log" I also tried with "import os" but still the same problem.
Note that os_log works fine.

```
import os
import os.log

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        os_log("test default")
        os_log_debug("test")
        return true
    }
...
}
```

...TestProject/AppDelegate.swift:23:3: Use of unresolved identifier 'os_log_debug'

I can not find anything in the doc that indicate that those should be treated differently.
I'm using Xcode 10.2.1 development target 12.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Swift there are two variants of `os_log()`:

```
public func os_log(_ type: OSLogType, dso: UnsafeRawPointer = #dsohandle,
                  log: OSLog = .default, _ message: StaticString, _ args: CVarArg...)

public func os_log(_ message: StaticString, dso: UnsafeRawPointer? = #dsohandle,
                   log: OSLog = .default, type: OSLogType = .default, _ args: CVarArg...)
```

I could not find the first one in the documentation, but the second variant is documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/2320718-os_log). Anyway: The type can be passed as an additional argument of type [`OSLogType`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/oslogtype):

```
os_log("default message")
os_log(.debug, "debug message")
os_log(.info, "info message")

// Or:
os_log("default message", type: .default)
os_log("debug message", type: .debug)
os_log("info message", type: .info)
```

Comment: Nice work around. Thank you.
Also i realised (a bit late) that the doc i was reading is for objective-c... Hence I didn't have the right info.

Comment: Note : there is no swift version of the doc for os_log: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/os_log?language=swift

Comment: @Lapieuvre: The documentation seems to be incomplete, I have added some information.